# divs coming coming up same in both mobile and desktop

Tags: html, mobile, bootstrap-4, desktop

I am trying to make two divs come up in same row in desktop, and one below the other in the mobile view. But it's appearing in same row in both desktop and mobile view. And when I am trying to use col-xs-* to achieve the same, it is not working. I am using bootstrap 4.

```
<section class="pb_section pt-0 pb-0" id="section-contact">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="pb_half py-5">
          <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
              <h2 class="mb-4 text-uppercase pb_letter-spacing-2">Write us</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <form action="#">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control p-3 rounded-0" id="name">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control p-3 rounded-0" id="email">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="message">Message</label>
                  <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control  p-3 rounded-0" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn pb_outline-dark pb_font-13 pb_letter-spacing-2  p-3 rounded-0" value="Send Message">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pb_half" id="map">

        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some issue with stack overflow editor. Can you try running the fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/1w02ngym/5/". The problem with the code is you have to use column structure with "pb_half" divs.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">


  <section class="pb_section pt-0 pb-0" id="section-contact">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pb_half py-5 col-lg-6">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
          <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
            <h2 class="mb-4 text-uppercase pb_letter-spacing-2">Write us</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <form action="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control p-3 rounded-0" id="name">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control p-3 rounded-0" id="email">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control  p-3 rounded-0" id="message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn pb_outline-dark pb_font-13 pb_letter-spacing-2  p-3 rounded-0" value="Send Message">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pb_half col-lg-6" id="map">
        <h1>
          This is Map
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Revert, if you have any other issues

Comment: Please tell, if you have any other concerns

Comment: No, there is another div that displays map, with the contact form. My concern is they both are coming together in both mobile and desktop view.

Comment: Updated the above code as per your requirement, Please check if it solves your problems

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="pb_section p-5" id="section-contact">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
            <h2 class="mb-4 text-uppercase pb_letter-spacing-2">Write us</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control p-3 rounded-0" id="name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control p-3 rounded-0" id="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control  p-3 rounded-0" id="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn pb_outline-dark pb_font-13 pb_letter-spacing-2  p-3 rounded-0" value="Send Message">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your code working fine for desktop and mobile both. In mobile div one after one and for desktop first 2 div in same row. And I have updated some layout changes in your code. You can try now.